# Network restoration problem after hibernation in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

In Ubuntu 16.04, i used sudo pm-hibernate command in terminal. System got hung and when i restarted manually i am having network connection problems. Not able to ping to other pc of the LAN.

Comment: try running `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Did you check if your PC had IP address?